# How to remove duplicated characters in char array, using java?

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans, char

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    char[] x = {'b', 'l', 'a', 'h', 'h', ' '};
    char[] y = {'g', 'o', 'g', 'o'};

    System.out.println(removeDuplicate(x, y));
    System.out.println(noDuplicate(y, x));

public static char[] removeDuplicate(char[] first, char[] second)
{  

   //used my append method (didn't enclose) to append the two words together
   char[] total1 = append(first, second);

   //stores character that have been encountered
   char[] norepeat = new char[total1.length];

   int index = 0;

   //store result
   char[] solution = new char[total1.length];

   boolean found = false;

   //for loop keeps running until blahh gogo is over
   for(int i = 0; i < total1.length; i++)
   {
       for(int m = 0; m <norepeat.length; m++)
       {
            if(total1[i] == norepeat[m])
            {  
                found = true;
                break;
            }
   }

    if (!found)
       {   
           norepeat[index] = total1[i];
           index++;

           solution[index] = total1[i];
           index++;
       }
   }

   return solution;
}
}
```

**Current Output:**

```
blah

go
```

**I Want the Output to be:**

```
blah go

goblah (space at the end)
```

The problem with my code is that it stops running after encountering the first repeat, so it doesn't even run the whole words at all. I believe that it has something to do with my nested for loop, but I am not sure. I tried writing it out on paper, but it doesn't seem to help any.

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: What is the logic by which you end up with `goblah` in your output?

Comment: Why you are not using hashSet ?? Use HashSet problem will be solved in O(N) time. Dont write code which is already written.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen In main when I printed out "System.out.println(noDuplicate(y, x));" I am now reading the char[] from y to x -- therefore read from gogo to blahh . Therefore for what I want the second output to be is goblah  after the duplicates has been removed. Hope I clarified that for you.

Comment: @nikeshjoshi I am a beginner java programmer, am just learning my basics right now. I have yet to learn about HashSet...

Comment: If your current output only outputs value of `first` (which is what seems to happen), perhaps your `append()` method doesn't work. --- What is the difference between `norepeat` and `solution`? I mean, other than `norepeat` gets all the even indexes assigned and `solution` gets all the odd indexes assigned, because you increment `index` twice in the `if (!found)` block. --- Maybe you should **debug** your code. See [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/5221149)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to assign the found variable as false in the beginning of the first  loop. After your first turn the value of found is always true.

```
for(int i=0;i<total1.length;i++)
{
 found=false;
 for(int m = 0; m <norepeat.length; m++)
   {      
        if(total1[i] == norepeat[m])
        {  
            found = true;
            break;
   }
```

You can also use set of characters instead of using char array.A set is a collection which doesn't allow duplication of elements.For more info. about sets you can visit this link.[Sets](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_set_interface.htmhttp://)

Comment: *Before* the inner loop, not inside it.

Comment: I agree with you it should be in the first loop before the beginning of second loop

Answer (score 0):

If the possible letters is the ASCII range, then you can use a simple boolean array to keep track of letters you've seen already:

```
boolean[] seen = new boolean[256];
```

If you don't modifying the original array of characters, then you can arrange unique elements to the beginning of the array, and then create a new array of the first `size` elements and return it.

```
int size = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < chars.length; j++) {
    char c = chars[j];
    if (!seen[c]) {
        chars[size++] = chars[j];
        seen[c] = true;
    }
}
return Arrays.copyOf(chars, size);
```

If the alphabet can be more than the ASCII range, you can use a `Set<Character>` to track characters seen.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution using Map and List as helpers. Input and output as char arrays are preserved.

Note that you should not init `solution` at the length of `total1` otherwise the char array will print blanks at the end.

```
public static char[] removeDuplicate(char[] first, char[] second){  

   //used my append method (didn't enclose) to append the two words together
   char[] total1 = append(first, second);

   //stores character that have been encountered
   Map<Character,Boolean> norepeat = new HashMap<Character,Boolean>();
   //store partial result
   List<Character> partSolution=new ArrayList<Character>();

    //for loop keeps running until blahh gogo is over
    for(int i = 0; i < total1.length; i++){
        if(! norepeat.containsKey(total1[i])) {   
            norepeat.put(total1[i], true) ;
            partSolution.add(total1[i]);
        }

    }

    //store final result
    char[] solution = new char[partSolution.size()];
    for(int i=0;i<partSolution.size();i++){
       solution[i]=partSolution.get(i);
    }    

    return solution;
```

}

Answer (score -1):

If you need to get rid of duplicate elements and to preserve the order of array you may use `LinkedHashSet`. Here is an example:

```
Set<Character> x = new LinkedHashSet<Character>(Arrays.asList(new Character[]{'b', 'l', 'a', 'h', 'h', ' '}));
Set<Character> y = new LinkedHashSet<Character>(Arrays.asList(new Character[]{'g', 'o', 'g', 'o'}));

System.out.println(x);
System.out.println(y);
```

**Output:**

```
[b, l, a, h,  ]
[g, o]
```

**Edit.** Here is an example how you may convert char[] to Character[] and vice versa:

```
char[] a = new char[]{'b', 'l', 'a', 'h', 'h', ' '};
Character[] boxed = IntStream.range(0, a.length).mapToObj(i -> a[i]).toArray(size -> new Character[size]);
char[] unboxed = IntStream.range(0, boxed.length).mapToObj(i -> String.valueOf(boxed[i])).collect(Collectors.joining()).toCharArray();
```

Comment: Input is `char[]`, not `Character[]`, and changing array type is likely not appropriate.